Observation process's drift depends on past observations
In nonlinear filtering theory, denote the underlying state process $X_t$, the observation process is typically written as $Y_t = \int_{0}^{t}h(X_{s})ds+B_{t}$ or its differential form, where $B_t$ is some Wiener process. The function $h$ is deterministic, but I wonder if there has been any theory worked out for the case where $Y_t = \int_{0}^{t}h(Y_{s},X_{s})ds+B_{t}$. I've looked up some extensions of standard filtering theory and mostly they are about the true state dynamics depending on past observations. Instead, I just need the observation process to be generalized. Any source of more info on this is greatly appreciated.
